# null in response from server

Tags: angular, http

I have a server sending back data, but there is a null at the end =>

```
{"result":{"status":2},"missionID":{"identifier":"9a"}}
null
```

what I do, is a simple http call :

```
  constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  createMission(params: API_MODEL.IMissionAPI): Observable<API_MODEL.CreateMissionResponse> {
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(`${environment.API_URL}/mission/create_mission`, params);
  }
```

but I get an error because of the null

> core.js:15724 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status:
>   200, statusText: "OK", url:
>   "http://localhost:8085/api/v1/mission/create_mission", ok: false,
>   …}error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position
>   56`

what am I missing ?

[image]

EDIT : it s called in

```
  @Effect()
  createMission$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.CreateMissionRequest>(featureActions.ActionTypes.CreateMissionRequest),
    withLatestFrom(this.store$),
    switchMap(([action, state]) =>
  this.dataService.createMission(state.missions.entities[action.payload.routeId]).pipe(
        map(response => // blablabla),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => // blablabla),
      )
    )
  );
```

the thing is in postman the same call make no null when the response type is JSON. but it put a null with the other reponse type. I do not have access to the server.

Comment: Where's your subscribe function?

Comment: it's an effect from ngrx that pipe and take the value, the problem is inside those lines I will add this tho.

Comment: Kindly check your server side code to avoid null at the end.

Comment: I understand, but I would put a break point where you do `.subscribe(res => ...` to see what's inside `res`. Is null or the variable holds some values?

Comment: @PadmapriyaVishnuvardhan the thing is in postman the same call make no null when the response type is JSON. but it put a null with the other reponse type. I do not have access to the server.

Comment: it seems some variable is displaying value on the backend. Thats why you are getting null. It has nothing to do with front end codes

Comment: @JacopoSciampi i go directly in the catchError, with an error message that I put in the main post about invalid n

Comment: True. The response will go in catchError, becos it is not a valid json response. Check your server side code which variable is set to display. If you are not sure, use postman to check if you are getting null there too

Comment: Well, then it seems to be a BE error. `Unexpected token n in JSON at position 56` I would check this line. Maybe you can get the JSON from BE and try to validate it using, for example, jsonlint

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene I precised with postman there are no null

Comment: Do you have any interceptors for httpclient where you appending something?